# Can't figure out how to create an XML SOAP Post in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I searched for examples and more, but it won't work. I don't know how i can create the piece of "POST code" for my xml message. I think i need a soapclient but i dont exactly know how i use one.

The WSDL file address: https://secure.intelly.nl/webservices/intellymodule001.asmx?WSDL

This is the xml message i created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
        xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
        xmlns:tns="http://extranet.intelly.nl/module001/" 
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:GetDomains xmlns:tns="http://extranet.intelly.nl/module001/">
        <tns:credentials>
            <ExternalProgramFunction>***</ExternalProgramFunction>
            <ExternalProgramID>***</ExternalProgramID>
            <Domain>***</Domain>
            <Username>***</Username>
            <Password>***</Password>
        </tns:credentials>
        <tns:message>
        </tns:message>
        <tns:message>
        </tns:message>
        <tns:searchParameters>
            <OnlyActive>True</OnlyActive>
        </tns:searchParameters>
    </tns:GetDomains>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a native [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php), below is an example using your input structure:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://secure.intelly.nl/webservices/intellymodule001.asmx?WSDL');

$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'ExternalProgramFunction' => 'xxx',
        'ExternalProgramID' => 'xxx',
        'Domain' => 'xxx',
        'UserName' => 'xxx',
        'Password' => 'xxx'
    ),
    'message' => array(),
    'searchParameters' => array(
        'OnlyActive' => true
    )
);

$response = $client->GetDomains($params);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the example! but if i use this, the response is:

    stdClass Object ( 
      [GetDomainsResult] => stdClass Object ( ) 
      [message] => stdClass Object ( 
        [Information] => stdClass Object ( ) 
        [Warnings] => stdClass Object ( ) 
        [Errors] => stdClass Object ( 
          [string] => Specify username ) 
        [ErrorCode] => ) )

so for some reason it wont get the username i filled in... (and of course i replaced all the x's with the good values)

any idea?